# Trying to install php-devel on AWS EC2 server to compile a PHP extension, but getting errors "httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.27-1.3.amzn1.x86_64"

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yum, httpd

I'm trying to install `php-devel` on an AWS EC2 server so I can compile a PHP extension. But I get an conflits error.

> --> Processing Conflict: httpd24-2.4.10-1.59.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd < 2.4.10
>   --> Processing Conflict: httpd24-tools-2.4.10-1.59.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd-tools < 2.4.10
>   --> Finished Dependency Resolution
>   Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.27-1.3.amzn1.x86_64
>   Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.27-1.3.amzn1.x86_64
>    You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
>    You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest

Looks like it want me to downgrade httpd24 to 2.2, but I had to change for 2.4 a few months ago in order to get SSL working...

I'm a noob at linux server admin, could anyone help me please ?
Thanks

Versions
OS : Amazon Linux 2013.3
PHP version : 5.4.26
httpd version : 2.4.10

Command : `yum install --enablerepo=remi php-devel`
Remi repo being http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/6/

PS : I found a file that seems to be ok at choon.net, but I don't really know if I can install it without any risk.
http://choonrpms.choon.net/centos/6/choonrpms-php-5.4/x86_64/php-devel-5.4.26-1.choon.centos6.x86_64.rpm

Comment: The `remi` and `choonrpms` repositories are not compatible with Amazon Linux. For that matter, there are almost no repos that are.

Comment: I agree with Michael. I've had very little luck with non Amazon repos. IMO having vetted repos for Amazon instance is worth the piece of mind. Have you checked the latest httpd version available on the latest AMI?

Comment: Actually, that post was a long time ago, I changed my perspective regarding my original goal. But thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `php54-devel` instead. I believe `php-devel` is the PHP 5.3 version in Amazon Linux, which has an Apache 2.2 dependency.

Comment: Same thing. 

At the beginning there is :  
`Loaded plugins: priorities, security, update-motd, upgrade-helper  
209 packages excluded due to repository priority protections  
Setting up Install Process  
Package php54-devel is obsoleted by php-devel, trying to install php-devel-5.4.31-1.el6.remi.x86_64 instead  
Resolving Dependencies` And at the end, the same conflict errors.